# WKWebView modify Action Sheet button

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, uialertcontroller

Is there a way to modify Action Sheet button?

In app I have a WebView. After long press on image it gives "Save image" button. After tapping it app crashes, because Photo Library permission isn't allowed.

What I'm trying to do is on "Save image" to check if there is permission for Photo Library. If there is save image, if not ask user for permission.

[image]

Comment: Always ask for permission.

Comment: In WebView delegate function, check for the url which is triggered on click of Save image button. If that is identified, you have what you want.

Comment: Asking for permission is ok while user allows it. If user denies and try to save image it'll lead to crash.

Comment: Please share your code.